# rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend does not produce accurate results outside of Rally using loginkey

Tags: rally

I am trying to create a Release trend chart, but I am getting different results if I run the code inside a rally app versus running the app outside of rally using a valid login key.  Below is the code in question.

After getting the chart to work correctly, I would love to be able to show some subset of the data, similar to the actual ReleaseDefectTrend chart inside of Rally, that lets you specifiy XXX number of days/weeks/months/etc.  Are there setting(s) for the config of the chart that will allow you to do this.

Thanks in advance!

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
            <!-- Copyright (c) 2011  Rally Software Development Corp.  All rights reserved -->
            <html>
            <head>
            <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js?debug=false"></script> -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.32/sdk.js?loginKey=myvalidloginkeyhere"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function onLoad() {

            //alert('ProjOID = ' + __PROJECT_OID__);
                   /
                   var rallyDataSource = new  rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("myvalidworkspaceID","myvalidprojectID","false","false");
                    var ddown1=document.getElementById("ddown1");
                    var config = { label: "Select a release " };
                    var releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(config,rallyDataSource);
                    releaseDropdown.display(ddown1,releaseSelected);

                }


                function releaseSelected(dropdown,eventArgs) {
                    var selectedItem=eventArgs.item;
                    var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
                    var releaseObjids =  new Array();
                    releaseObjids[1]=selectedItem.ObjectID;
                    displayChart1(releaseObjids[1]);
                }

                function displayChart1(release) {
                    var config = {
                        report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend,
                        //itle: 'Technical Debt',
                        width : 600,
                        height: 250,
                        releases: release
                    };
                    alert('chart1 release = ' + release);

                    var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
                    var div1=document.getElementById("div1");
                    report.display(div1);
               }

                rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
             <td align="center"><div id="ddown1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td><div id="div1"></div></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I have since found that I could also use rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.DefectTrend chart instead, and to achieve the time interval want, I would use the below config.

          var config = {
              report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.DefectTrend,
              width : 600,
              height: 250,
              interval: "Days",
              intervals_back: 30
          };
However, I still have the same issue, Works great inside of Rally custom app, but when I access the same unchanged code in its own html page outside of Rally, all of the lines on this chart are flat.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no hardcoded Object IDs of releases in your code, and workspace is also not specified. All WS API queries are bound to a workspace, and in the absence of specified workspace and a default for a given user there is no guarantee that what you see inside Rally is going to be the same outside. To narrow this down, you do not need to use login key in this stage of troubleshooting. Please make sure  the app works outside of Rally as expected - the login key only allows you to avoid the prompt to login. The scope is not specified in your code, but the app needs to pull available releases from somewhere. 
Before you customize the original code found [here](https://help.rallydev.com/standard-reports) see if the original code produces identical results for you outside and inside of Rally when you hard code Object ID of a specific release, and then move on to more complex scenarios when you have multiple ObjectIDs hardcoeded, and only then try to use a variable set dynamically from a dropdown value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="Name" content="Component Example: Standard Report">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/1.26/sdk.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function initPage() {
       var config = {
           report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend,
           width : 800,
           height: 400,
       releases: [1111,2222]
         };
       var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
       report.display("aDiv");
     }

     rally.addOnLoad(initPage);
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="aDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For more info see [Apps Outside of Rally](https://help.rallydev.com/apps-outside-rally)

Generally standard reports are canned reports and cannot be customized further outside of what the JSON configuration object allows. AppSDK1 allows you to load a report in a custom page by providing access to them via this syntax:

```
report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend
```

but if you want to zoom in, to display more information, perhaps in a chart, this has to be coded from scratch.

Comment: I tried your code with a valid release, and it seems to work fine both in and out out Rally without the login key on Safari browser.  However on chrome it seems to not work, which is strange because when I use the loginkey, Safari has problems logging in.  

Seems like I actually want to use the DefectTrend chart so I can control the interval, but I run into the same is of it working on Safari and flat lines on google.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Let's leave loginkey out of this for now. It works in Safari in and out of Rally, but shows a flat line in Chrome? Please log out of Rally in both browsers . I assume that at least in one of those you were logged in another tab. Now load this app in both browsers outside of Rally - you will be prompted to login to Rally. Login  using the same user credenials in both browsers. Do the charts look identical now in both browsers outside of Rally? How does the data compare to the data displayed when the charts are loaded inside Rally?

Comment: Ok, I have been staring at this for way to long.. I logged both browswers out, and tried again.  Both got a login for both and used the same credentials for both.  Both came up originally with flat lines, which was different than before.  I soon realized that the flatlines were result of the default project and not the browser, for when I went into rally, and changed the default page, both browsers showed the correct info. Now I just need to make it work with the rallyDataSource.  For the DefectTrend chart, you can specify the interval, you wouldn't have a code snippet handy would you?

Comment: John, the config properties you're looking for are "interval" (Days, Weeks, Months, Years) and "intervals_back" (the number of intervals) to chart.